# Read Parquet metadata on JVM

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, parquet

I am currently using `pyarrow` to read `parquet` metadata as shown below. We are however a JVM shop and we would like to have libraries and utilities written in Scala/Java, if possible. Are there equivalent libraries on JVM to do the same?

```
def print_parquet_metadata(file_path):
    pq_file = pq.ParquetFile(file_path)
    data = [["columns:", pq_file.metadata.num_columns],
            ["rows:", pq_file.metadata.num_rows],
            ["row_groups:", pq_file.metadata.num_row_groups]
            ]
    print(data)
```

Comment: On top of my head: parquet4s in Scala.

Comment: Thanks. Looked at it before posting the question. But it doesn't seem to have features to retrieve metadata without going through the data.